# Elasticsearch create new document too slow

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch, the case is I want process data from oracle DB ,and upload result to es using c# http post method
And I found that when I use single thread the average process time about 50ms,when using 10 threds the average process time go up to about 500ms, and 20 threads 1000ms
It seems like the elastic process my request one by one
I tried add num of shards and didn't work
my post URL like this:http://localhost:9200/indexname/_doc
also I tried add a unique ID tov (http://localhost:9200/indexname/_doc/_id), also didn't work
Is there anything I didn't config right?

Comment: solved.thank u.my code's fault

Answer (score 1):

if you are running more than one thread, you should be really be looking at using the `_bulk` API here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/docs-bulk.html

it's far more efficient than many threads